# Adding a video by filtering content in WordPress with add_filter()

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a video to the home page of a site. I have created a child theme and I am filtering the content to the home page using add_filter(). The problem is that the video is showing but none of the other content will show up that was showing before.

How can I get the video plus the original content to show up?

Here is the code that I have added to functions.php;

```
    add_filter('the_content', 'spd_video');

    function spd_video ($content){
if(is_front_page()){
 $content = '<div class="fullscreen-bg">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/I_Waited_VA_Logo.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
            <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I_Watied_VA_Video_1_Long_01.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I-Watied-VA-Video-1-Long.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            </div>';
    }
    return $content;
    }

    ?>
```

**CSS**

```
    .fullscreen-bg {
position: relative;
top: 104px;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -100;
    }

    .fullscreen-bg__video {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
.fullscreen-bg {
    background: url('http://iwaitedva.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/I_Waited_VA_Logo.png') center center / cover no-repeat;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing content with video completely instead of appending the video to the content. I would do it this way, depending on where you want to place video, on top or on bottom of content. So really $video.$content .. or $content.$video

```
add_filter('the_content', 'spd_video');

    function spd_video ($content){
if(is_front_page()){
 $video = '<div class="fullscreen-bg">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/I_Waited_VA_Logo.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
            <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I_Watied_VA_Video_1_Long_01.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I-Watied-VA-Video-1-Long.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            </div>';

     $content = $video . $content;
    }
    return $content;
    }
```